# Symmetric Random walk on $\mathbb {Z}^d$

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

> > Consider the symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^d $. Symmetric means that the probability of going into any of the $2^d$ directions is $1/2^d$. Starting in 0, what is the probability of returning to 0 in n steps?

---

My solution is

$$
p_{00}^{(n)}=\binom {n}{n/2}^d \frac{1}{2^{dn}}.
$$

Because for each dimension the steps in the one direction have to be the same as in the opposite direction and for each dimension there a $\binom {n}{n/2}$ possibilities to do so.

Am I right?

Comment: the $^d$ is at the wrong place!

Comment: Why? Not at the binomial coefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This time, there are $2d$ directions to choose from.

From the formula for $d=2$, you will have to change the binomial coefficient to
$$
\frac {n!}{\left(a_1!\right)^2 
\left(a_2!\right)^2\dots \left(a_{d}!\right)^2 
}$$for every  choice of $a_1\dots a_{d}$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^{d} a_i = n/2$ ($a_i$ is the number of moves made in the direction $+ e_i$) and the probability replaced accordingly by
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{d} \left(\frac1{2d}\right)^{2a_i}
$$

Then the global answer is
$$
p_{d,n} =  \sum_{\sum_{i=1}^{d} a_i=n/2} 
\frac {n!}{\left(a_1!\right)^2 
\left(a_2!\right)^2\dots \left(a_{d}!\right)^2 
}
\prod_{i=1}^{d} \left(\frac1{2d}\right)^{2a_i}
$$

Comment: To be honest i do not understand a word. 

Comment: @mathfemi: there is no more 2 ways to go, but 2d. each time you go somewhere and back to starting point, if you make $a_i$ move in the $+e_i$ direction, you also have to make $a_i$ moves in the $-e_i$ direction.

Comment: Now with a fixed $(a_1\dots a_d)$ choice of directions, the number of corresponding paths is the first thing I wrote (which replaces the binomial coefficient you wrote, look at the case $d=1$, $a_1 = n/2$ to convince yourself).

Comment: Could you please explain the first formula you write down and why the sum is $\leq$ n/2?

Comment: consider $d=2, n=4$. There are 4 ways: U, L, R, D for up, left right and down. Let us consider $a_1 =  a_2 = 1$. The formula is the number of words such as $DLRU$, so that there is $a_1$ U moves and $a_2$ L moves, and as much move in the other direction ($a_1$ D moves for each U and $a_1$ R move for each L). To be able to go back, it is necessary that $\sum a_i\le n/2$ obviously.

Comment: What are $a_1, a_2$? Did not get that yet.

Comment: it is the number of moves in a certain direction.

Comment: $a_1=1$ means one step to right, $a_2=1$ means one step above?

Comment: exactly.${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: Ok, now I see what the first formula means. But how does one get it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17972/discussion-between-mookid-and-mathfemi).

Comment: Doesn't $\prod_{i=1}^{d} \left(\frac1{2d}\right)^{2a_i}$ equals $\left(\frac1{2d}\right)^{n}$?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula works correctly for $d=1$ (of course) and also for $d=2$.  The way to see $d=2$ is that each step changes $x+y$ by $\pm 1$ each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and also, each step changes $x-y$ by $\pm 1$ each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and those results are independent.  So it is valid to multiply the two individual probabilities of ending at the origin, which is what your formula does.

Unfortunately, for $d >2$ (random walk in more than 2 dimensions), there is no similar clever reason why your formula would work.  And in fact, for a 2-step random walk in 3 dimensions, the probability of ending at the origin is $\frac{1}{6}$ whilst your formula gives an answer of $\frac{1}{8}$.

(I've always wanted to use the word "whilst" in a sentence.)